# Unable to send a correct request using typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to get the values from the `database` as the user types in the `typeahead` text field.

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" id="user-keyword" type="text" placeholder="Username" />

var userList = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote: {
            url: "PC/data_requests.php?request=get_user_list_for_kw"
          },
        replace: function(url, uriEncodedQuery) {
            val = $('#user-keyword').val();
            if (!val) return url;
            return url + '?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(val)
          }
    });

    $('#user-keyword').typeahead(null, {
      name: 'user-list',
      display: 'value',
      source: userList
    });
```

But this doesn't work. I need to send the value from the text field, which is the keyword corresponding to which the matching strings will be sent.  First, the ajax request fires only once when I try to write for the first time and second how to send the keyword from the text field?

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does your remote url work?  What does it return? What url is getting called when you attempt to use the typeahead?

Comment: @whipdancer `PC/data_requests.php?request=get_user_list_for_kw` gets called but only once. I want to pass the keywords also from the `typeahead` field everytime I write something.

Comment: I understand that it gets called once.  I just wanted to verify that 1) the url works and returns data when you manually call it 2) that when you examine the call in your browser dev tools, that you see the expected URL

Comment: I think `remote` options are set incorrectly.  Which version are you using?